# New Galaxy Note 3 error: "forced to stop for an unauthorized attempt to access system in your device"

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I am getting reports of a new error message coming from Samsung Galaxy Note 3 devices.  The error message includes this text: "forced to stop for an unauthorized attempt to access system in your device".  Searching tells me this is related to SELinux now being turned on in the latest Samsung firmware, but I am not sure what to do about this.  Does anyone know a) what an app might do to cause this? and b) how to fix it.

Comment: This question belongs to http://android.stackexchange.com

Comment: Actually, I am a developer and trying to fix my app.  The link you gave is more for enthusiasts/power users of Android.  So, I am not a user trying to work around this problem, but a dev, trying to understand how to modify my app, so users don't get this error in the first place. So, this is the correct place for this question.  Sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: It seems to me you made clear you are trying to fix *an app* not *your app*, and you don't even know which one is causing this, if any. I don't see how this could relate to programming from your part, unless its *your app* that is causing the problem.

Comment: @Havenard, if it wasn't *corbin's* app causing the problem, he wouldn't receive error reports for it, plain and simple. The `READ_LOGS` permission is deprecated as of Android 4.x. Now *all* apps can read their own logs without requesting any permission, and no (user-) app can read another app's logs at all. Crash reports are only sent to the publisher/developer of an app. There's nothing in corbin's post that would suggest he's trying to debug a different app.

Comment: @Corbin - read your stack-traces carefully and try to work out which part of your code causes the crash. Ideally, get yourself a Tab III device for debugging.

Comment: @Havenard I said "sorry if I was unclear".  Why I posted the question and why I posted it here should be clear based on my response.  Continuing on ...

Comment: @323go the report was only emails from users.  For whatever reason the app continue to works after the error and I do not see crash logs in the developer console for the Play Market.  I will see if I can get someone to do a catlog after seeing the issue.